# Can I output to a VM running SQL Server from Azure Analytics job?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Generating output to a Azure SQL database is supported, but I was shocked when I found that the portal does not allow to specify a SQL Server database running on a VM. Is not this supported?
We need to store lots of data coming through the ASA jobs, and use SQL Jobs, that's why we were planning to use a SQL Server VM.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot configure the SQL Database running on VM as an output to the ASA job.

However, Azure provides SQL services with 2 variants

**Microsoft Azure SQL Database (Azure SQL Database)  as PaaS**

where lower stack is managed by Microsoft Azure and billed as pay-as-you-go model.

and

**SQL Server in Azure Virtual Machine (VM) as IaaS**  where user owns the VM and make any changes, including licences for the SQL database.

> the Microsoft Azure SQL Database provided as PaaS is configurable as
> ASA output.

Answer (score 1):

one idea might be to create and Event Hub output for the ASA and then consume it from there using any sort of application to write into an IaaS SQL DB. The application that consumes the data can also be hosted as a Web App as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, that's another option. We would like to stay in ASA. I just wanted to validate this limitation. Thanks